# trouble uploading image from remote server using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery

this is the code

```
$.ajax({
       url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/changepicture",
       type: 'POST',
       data: formData1,
       crossDomain: true,
       async: true,
       cache: false,
       contentType: false,
       processData: false, 
       success: function (data) {
       var pictureValue = decodeURIComponent(data);
       var imageToReplace = 
      '<imgsrc=http://127.0.0.1:8080/public/images/'+pictureValue+ '>';
       $("#topImageAjax1").replaceWith(imageToReplace);
            console.log(data);
       },
       error: function (data){
           alert("Oooops cannot connect to server now");
           console.log('something went wrong!!!')
       }
```

on the browser console am getting:
GET http://127.0.0.1:8080//public/images/0001b.jpg 404 (Not Found)
please how do I get this solved.

Comment: You're missing a space on your `<img>` tag. Not sure what your remote script is doing with the data? 404 means the image must have a different path to the one you're using to find it or it's not there.

Comment: This is a complete guessing game for us. We have no idea where it should be or where it actually is or what you do with it in your server code

Comment: the image is in public/images, am returning the name of the image and passing it as a value for the "pictureValue"

Comment: @Alex: I have included the space but it still not working.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache with CTRL + F5?

Comment: cleared it but still not working

Comment: Pretty sure it's cause the //public should be /public.  The only double backslash should be following the protocol.